# I installed Eclipse ADT without any error message, but after rebooting, I can't see any Android plug-in

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

I've developed Android apps with Eclipse Indigo for half a year now without any problem. However, since I updated two days ago to the last version of the Android SDK, things started to go wrong. I had to continously do a Project->Clean by hand to avoid unfair syntax errors with no justification all the time. And even worse, I started having lot of trouble signing final APK with the Export Wizard.

So I decided to delete eclipse entirely and install the latest version, Juno, and the Android SDK and the Android ADT plugin all again. My problem is that now my brand new Eclipse installation doesn't show any Android option after installing the Android ADT plugin.

Whenever I start Eclipse, I see the following error Log appear, but I have no idea if it is related or not:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2012-07-15 18:14:31.879
!MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
!SESSION 2012-07-15 18:14:49.877 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.5.0_30
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=es_ES
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/XXX/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/XXX/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2012-07-15 18:14:53.885
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
```

My system:

MacBookPro MacOS 10.5.8, Eclipse Classic Juno (last version), Android SDK (last version), Eclipse ADT plugin (installed from eclipse itself with no results)

**EDIT**

If I check Eclipse->About->Installation Details->Plug-ins or Eclipse->About->Installation Details->Features, no Android plug-in appers, and it should. However, it appears in Eclipse->About->Installation Details-Installed Software and in Eclipse->About->Installation Details->Installation History. Also, if I go to Help->Install new software->ADT plugin->Developer Tools, I get the followig output:

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Tracer for OpenGL ES" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
```

If I cant remove a plug-in in Eclipse, how could I know what is the problem with the installation of the plug-in???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

I saw that the last version of Android SDK (20, the one driving me crazy) requires at least MacOS v10.5.8 and JVM v1.6. For me, that makes no sense, since the official JVM v1.6 update package for MacOS requires v10.6, not v10.5.8, so I updated the entire OS to 10.6 and finally everything is working: Eclipse Juno for Mobile Developers + JVM v1.6 + Eclipse ADT + Android SDK v20.

It's curious, because Google docs says that the previous version of the Android SDK also required JVM v1.6, but I used it for months with v1.5 and no problems at all.

Answer (score 2):

When you upgraded your SDK you likely needed to upgrade your ADT plugin as well. You can check if there are plugin updates by going to Help > Check for Updates.

Juno is a brand new Eclipse release, and I have no idea if it's (fully) compatible with ADT yet or if there is perhaps an update coming for it. Regardless, I wouldn't use it yet and would stick to Indigo.

Just make sure you have the latest SDK and latest ADT installed or else you see weird problems like you describe.

Comment: Thanks, OK, I will try reinstalling Indigo again then... The thing is that I managed to install everything (Eclipse Juno + Eclipse ADT + Android SDK) in Windows 7. My problem is only in my Mac OS laptop anyway...

Comment: Wow, the exactly same problem with Eclipse Indigo. I installed the Eclipse ADT on it without any error message, but after rebooting I can't see any Android option. It is something with Eclipse in my laptop then, but what?