# installed ADT on Eclipse Juno, but can't create Android Projects (32 bit only)

Tags: adt, eclipse-juno

I have two machines, a 64 bit machine and a 32 bit machine, both running Win7.  I followed these steps on both:

1. Extract Eclipse to a directory.
2. Run Eclipse in Admin mode.
3. Select Help/Install New Software
4. Click the Add button
5. Enter the following location: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
6. Enter the following name: ADT Plugin
7. Selected 'developer tools'
8. Installed the package.
9. Allowed Eclipse to restart.

There were no errors in either case.

On my 64 bit machine, I now can create new android projects, I see Android options under Window/Preferences... and in help/about I see many android options.

On my 32 bit machine I see none of these things. I DO see the packages as installed (help/about), but NOT the plugins (plugin tab of help/about).

When I launch Eclipse on my 32 bit machine, there are a few errors listed in the error log.  Things like this:

> java.io.IOException: Unable to resolve plug-in "platform:/plugin/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt/icons/android_file.png".
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.parse(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:64)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLPluginConnection.resolve(PlatformURLPluginConnection.java:75)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.boot.PlatformURLHandler.openConnection(PlatformURLHandler.java:67)
>       at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.protocol.URLStreamHandlerProxy.openConnection(URLStreamHandlerProxy.java:112)
>       at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformURLConverter.toFileURL(PlatformURLConverter.java:33)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(FileLocator.java:206)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.getFilePath(URLImageDescriptor.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.resource.URLImageDescriptor.createImage(URLImageDescriptor.java:157)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:227)
>       at org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor.createImage(ImageDescriptor.java:205)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.getImage(SWTPartRenderer.java:178)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.createTab(StackRenderer.java:731)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.processContents(LazyStackRenderer.java:134)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:635)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:725)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:696)
>       at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:690)
>       at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)

I tried using the downloaded archive as well.  (ADT-20.0.3.zip)  This works fine on the 64 bit machine but fails to install at all on the 32 bit machine with the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 20.0.3.v201208082019-427395) requires 'org.eclipse.wst.sse.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

This is a similar problem (with different error messages) to this one, but I checked and the solutions posted here do not work for me.
[I installed Eclipse ADT without any error message, but after rebooting, I can't see any Android plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494117/i-installed-eclipse-adt-without-any-error-message-but-after-rebooting-i-cant)

Answer (score 0):

Run Eclipse in non-admin mode.

Running in admin mode made a lot of mess for me. When I launched Eclipse again in non-admin mode, a migration wizard popped up fixing everything swiftly (re-launching Eclipse at the end).